# Is there a way of displaying flutter code output on a webpage

Tags: flutter, dart, web

I was wondering if there was a way of displaying what some flutter code that a user could write in a browser.
I am planning on making a web app that allows users to write some flutter code on a left panel and the output would display on the write panel.
Any help or advice is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Flutter can't run as JIT (Just-In-Time) code in the browser since it no longer ships with a web engine for dart; instead dart is compiled to JS ahead of time. To execute an arbitrary flutter program in the browser, you'd need to send the code to a server, perform a build, then send it back as an application.

Comment: Ah I see. That has been very useful. Thank you 